# How to use regular expression for xpath of XML in xslt?

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, xpath

I have my XML as below:

```
<pi:Additional_Information>
 <pi:Allocation_Cost_Center_1 > test value cost 1 </pi:Allocation_Cost_Center_1>
 <pi:Allocation_Cost_Center_2 > test value cost 2 </pi:Allocation_Cost_Center_2>
 <pi:Allocation_Cost_Center_3 > test value cost 3 </pi:Allocation_Cost_Center_2>
 <pi:Allocation_Cost_Center_4 > test value cost 4 </pi:Allocation_Cost_Center_2>
 <pi:Allocation_Region_1 >test value region 1</pi:Allocation_Region_1>
 <pi:Allocation_Region_2 >test value region 2</pi:Allocation_Region_2>
 <pi:Allocation_Region_3 >test value region 3</pi:Allocation_Region_3>
 <pi:Allocation_Region_4 >test value region 4</pi:Allocation_Region_4>
 <pi:Allocation_Location_1>Berlin</pi:Allocation_Location_1>
 <pi:Allocation_Location_2>Berlin</pi:Allocation_Location_2>
 <pi:Allocation_Location_3>Berlin</pi:Allocation_Location_3>
 <pi:Allocation_Location_4>Berlin</pi:Allocation_Location_4>
</pi:Additional_Information>
```

I need to loop through all the tags ending with one in first loop, in next loop all tags ending in 2 and so on.....

I am using XSLT 2.0. Expected output is as below:

(Row one)

test value cost 1 test value region 1 Berlin

(Row two)

test value cost 2 test value region 2 Berlin

(Row three)

test value cost 3 test value region 3 Berlin

(Row four)

test value cost 4 test value region 4 Berlin

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post the expected output of your example, and what exactly is your difficulty in getting it. -- Note that the input your show us is not a well-formed XML document the prefix `pi` is not bound to a namespace).

Comment: What a poor XML design! Element names should never contain instance data like this.

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? Regular expressions are not available in 1.0.

Comment: I have update the question above to answer your questions, ignore the namespace thing I have already got that covered.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way you could look at it:

```
<xsl:template match="/pi:Additional_Information">
    <xsl:variable name="nodes" select="*" />
    <xsl:variable name="rows" select="count($nodes) div 3" />
    <xsl:for-each select="0 to $rows - 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="$nodes[(position() - 1) mod $rows = current()]"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This is assuming there are always 3 types of nodes (and therefore 3 values per row), and that they are sorted by type and by row.

Otherwise you could use:

```
<xsl:template match="pi:Additional_Information">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="tokenize(name(), '_')[last()]">        
        <xsl:value-of select="current-group()"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

This groups the nodes by whatever comes after the last underscore in their name.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0:

```
   <xsl:template match="pi:Additional_Information">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="replace(name(), '[A-Za-z_]', '')">
     <loop index="{current-grouping-key()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
     </loop>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `group-by="replace(name(), '[A-Za-z_]', '')"`?

Comment: Thanks, fixed as suggested.